# What resources are available for academics of color to navigate academia from postdoc onward?

Tags: united-states, academic-life, ethnicity

Many people have commented that there is a "hidden curriculum" in academia. In colleges, there are student groups that discuss issues related to race and ethnicity. In industry, there are some professional organizations and mentoring resources developed by people of color that are specifically designed to help other people of color navigate the work environment. These panels discuss barriers that people of color face, like the "glass ceiling" in promotion to leadership positions. One example: Stanford Business School has a (not free) Asian American executive development program. These resources tend to be geared towards people in a non-academic workplace.

As someone who is currently not in industry, my question is: What resources, if any, are available to me in academia, from other researchers of color that I can access? Normally I would just talk to senior faculty, but on issues in academia specifically related to race/ethnicity, there might not be many (if any) non-white faculty in the department to turn to.

Here are some of the things I have in mind that it would be really nice to have someone in a more senior position to discuss with (I'm Asian-American):

- microaggressions
- decline in diverse hiring in economic uncertainty (https://sociologicalscience.com/articles-v8-15-308/)
- why faculty of color have lower tenure rates than white faculty and what the implications are for me
- things I should be cognizant of as a minority in a predominantly white department
- what faculty of color have to do differently, if anything, to succeed
- senior leadership positions, and how to increase representation in those roles
- which departments are more welcoming for faculty of color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of any organization for the general situation: "academics of color" might be a too diverse group for such an organization to exist. Consider zooming in. For instance, [Black In AI](https://blackinai.github.io/#/) has been running for several years now, and focuses on "presence and inclusion of Black people in the field of AI by creating space for sharing ideas, fostering collaborations, mentorship and advocacy". That sounds like the kind of thing you seek, but if your research is not in Artificial Intelligence, this may not be helpful to you. In that case, seek similar initiatives for your own ethnicity and research field.